# How to improve logic if any of 3 values are false then enter the code block?

Tags: c#, .net

I have 3 bool variables. I am using `Int.TryParse` to parse the values of these variables.
I would like to develop a condition if any of the 3 values are false then enter the IF code block, but if all 3 values are true, then don't enter the IF block.

How should I specify this condition in c#?

```
bool var1 = int.TryParse("23", out k);
bool var2 = int.TryParse("Ask", out j);
bool var3 = int.TryParse("45", out i);
```

Comment: `Int.TryParse("Ask", out j)` is never `true`, though. There are no variables being parsed here, you're just feeding the function constants. What is the broader context of this code? The only true basic numbers in programming are 0, 1, 2, and "many". Parsing exactly three things is unusual and normally suggests a loop and/or collection.

Comment: For simplicity, I have hardcoded the string values, it can actually contain a number or no value, thus true or false.

Comment: Do you need the parsed values of the strings that actually were parseable, inside the `for` loop?

Comment: I don't need the parsed values, I need to check whether any of 3 parsed values is false.

Comment: you are not parsing bools though, you are parsing strings that contain digits or characters.

Answer (score 2):

I hope that I've got your question right. This is how the condition could look like.

```
if (!int.TryParse("23", out k) || 
                !int.TryParse("Ask", out j) || 
                !int.TryParse("45", out i)) {
                Console.WriteLine("Can't parse.");
            }
            else{
                Console.WriteLine($"{k} {j} {i}");
            }
```

Comment: But, if all are true then it will say Can't parse.

Comment: no - `!true OR !true OR !true` will be `false`, and the `else`  will be executed

Comment: this code can be simplified to `Console.WriteLine("Cant parse")`

Answer (score -1):

(Suggesting this based on OP's comment *I don't need the parsed values, I need to check whether any of 3 parsed values is false.*)

---

If you could keep your strings in an array and don't care about the parsed values (or which of the strings are in fact parseable), you could do as follows:

```csharp
string[] strings = new[] { "23", "Ask", "45" };

var allAreParseable = strings.All(str => int.TryParse(str, out _));

if (!allAreParseable)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Not all values could be parsed");
}
```